# Sort a subset of a python list to have the same relative order as in other list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-2.7, sorting

So having a list say `b = [b1, b2, b3]` I want to be able to sort a list `a` in such a way that all `bi`'s that also exist in `a` have the same relative order as in `b` - leaving the rest of `a`'s elements alone. So

```
a = [ b1, x, b3, y, b2] -> [ b1, x, b2, y, b3]
a = [ b1, x, b2, y, b3] -> no change
a = [ b1, x, y, b2]     -> no change
a = [ b3, x, b1, y, b2] -> [ b1, x, b2, y, b3]
```

b of course may be a tuple or any other ordered structure. What I came up with

```
bslots = dict((x, a.index(x)) for x in a if x in b)
bslotsSorted = sorted(bslots.keys(), key=lambda y: b.index(y))
indexes = sorted(bslots.values())
for x,y in zip(bslotsSorted, indexes):
  a[y] = x
```

is clumsy and O(n^2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First create a dictionary using items from `b` where the key is the item and value is its index, we will use this to sort the matched items in `a` later on.
- Now filter out item from `a` that are present in that dict, dict provides O(1) lookup.
- Now sort this list of filtered items and convert it to an iterator.
- Now loop over `a` again and for each item check if is present in dict then fetch its value from iterator otherwise use it as is.

```
def solve(a, b):
    dct = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(b)}
    items_in_a = [x for x in a if x in dct]
    items_in_a.sort(key=dct.get)
    it = iter(items_in_a)
    return [next(it) if x in dct else x for x in a]
...
>>> b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
>>> a = [ 'b1', 'x', 'b3', 'y', 'b2']
>>> solve(a, b)
['b1', 'x', 'b2', 'y', 'b3']
>>> a = [ 'b1', 'x', 'b2', 'y', 'b3']
>>> solve(a, b)
['b1', 'x', 'b2', 'y', 'b3']
>>> a = [ 'b1', 'x', 'y', 'b2']
>>> solve(a, b)
['b1', 'x', 'y', 'b2']
>>> a = [ 'b3', 'x', 'b1', 'y', 'b2']
>>> solve(a, b)
['b1', 'x', 'b2', 'y', 'b3']
```

Overall time complexity is going to be max of `(O(len(a)), O(len(b)), O(items_in_a_length log items_in_a_length)`.

Comment: Note that this requires the objects in `b` to be hashable. If the objects in `b` are sets or lists (etc), you may be able to use the raw `id` as the lookup value instead.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer answers the question as asked, but my actual problem was a bit more restrictive - namely I would like to keep items in the same relative positions in `a` as much as possible. So the accepted answer (and my original attempt) would:

```
b = [ A, E, B ]
a = [ A, B, C, D, E, Z] -> [ A, E, C, D, B, Z ]
```

I would like to just "bubble up" the out-of-order items so they lose as few of their ancestors as possible: `[ A, B, C, D, E, Z ] -> [ A, C, D, E, B, Z ]`. Note that previously E would lose ancestors C and D, while now only loses B as required. Marginally tested:

```
def reorder(a, b):
    bb = b[:]
    b_in_a = [x for x in a if x in set(b)]
    w = dict((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(a))
    while b_in_a:
        for i, (ordered, current) in enumerate(zip(bb, b_in_a)):
            if ordered != current:
                for j, x in enumerate(b_in_a[i:]):
                    if x == ordered: break
                    to = w[ordered] + 1 + j
                    w = dict((x,i if i < to else i+1) for x,i in w.iteritems())
                    w[x] = to # bubble them up !
                b_in_a.remove(ordered)
                bb = bb[i + 1:]
                b_in_a = b_in_a[i:]
                break
        else:
            break
    aa = a[:]
    a.sort(key=w.__getitem__)
    print aa, '-', b, ' -> ', a

# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] - ['A', 'E', 'B']  ->  ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B']
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] - ['A', 'E', 'C', 'B']  ->  ['A', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'B', 'F']
```

Comment: @ AshwiniChaudhary: any clever optimizations for this one ?