# Sort a sublist of elements in a list leaving the rest in place

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, key

Say I have a sorted list of strings as in:

```
['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

Now I want to sort based on the trailing numerical value for the `B`s - so I have:

```
['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

One possible algorithm would be to hash up a regex like `regex = re.compile(ur'(B)(\d*))`, find the indices of the first and last `B`, slice the list, sort the slice using the regex's second group, then insert the sorted slice. However this seems too much of a hassle. Is there a way to write a key function that "leaves the item in place" if it does not match the regex and only
sorts the items (sublists) that match ?

**Note:** the above is *just an example*; I don't necessarily know the pattern (or I may want to also sort C's, or any string that has a trailing number in there). Ideally, I'm looking for an approach to the general problem of sorting only subsequences which match a given criterion (or failing that, just those that meet the specific criterion of a given prefix followed by a string of digits).

Comment: @IvanChaer: "Say I have a sorted list of strings as in:..." - the list _is_ lexicographically sorted to begin with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simple case where you just want to sort trailing digits numerically and their non-digit prefixes alphabetically, you need a key function which splits each item into non-digit and digit components as follows:

```
'AB123' -> ['AB', 123]
'CD'    -> ['CD']
'456'   -> ['', 456]
```

> ***Note:*** In the last case, the empty string `''` is not strictly necessary in CPython 2.x, as integers sort before strings – but that's an implementation detail rather than a guarantee of the language, and in Python 3.x it **is** necessary, because strings and integers can't be compared at all.

You can build such a key function using a list comprehension and [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

def trailing_digits(x):
   return [
       int(g) if g.isdigit() else g
       for g in re.split(r'(\d+)$', x)
   ]
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> s1 = ['11', '2', 'A', 'B', 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'C', 'C11', 'C2']
```

```
>>> sorted(s1, key=trailing_digits)
['2', '11', 'A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Once you add the restriction that only strings with a particular prefix or prefixes have their trailing digits sorted numerically, things get a little more complicated.

The following function builds and returns a key function which fulfils the requirement:

```
def prefixed_digits(*prefixes):
    disjunction = '|'.join('^' + re.escape(p) for p in prefixes)
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=%s)(\d+)$' % disjunction)
    def key(x):
        return [
            int(g) if g.isdigit() else g
            for g in re.split(pattern, x)
        ]
    return key
```

The main difference here is that a precompiled regex is created (containing a lookbehind constructed from the supplied prefix or prefixes), and a key function using that regex is returned.

Here are some usage examples:

```
>>> s2 = ['A', 'B', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'C', 'C11', 'C2', 'D12', 'D2']
```

```
>>> sorted(s2, key=prefixed_digits('B'))
['A', 'B', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'C11', 'C2', 'D12', 'D2']
```

```
>>> sorted(s2, key=prefixed_digits('B', 'C'))
['A', 'B', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'C2', 'C11', 'D12', 'D2']
```

```
>>> sorted(s2, key=prefixed_digits('B', 'D'))
['A', 'B', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'C11', 'C2', 'D2', 'D12']
```

If called with no arguments, `prefixed_digits()` returns a key function which behaves identically to `trailing_digits`:

```
>>> sorted(s1, key=prefixed_digits())
['2', '11', 'A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'C2', 'C11']
```

**Caveats:**

1. Due to a restriction in Python's `re` module regarding lookbhehind syntax, multiple prefixes must have the same length.
2. In Python 2.x, strings which are purely numeric will be sorted numerically regardless of which prefixes are supplied to `prefixed_digits()`. In Python 3, they'll cause an exception (except when called with no arguments, or in the special case of `key=prefixed_digits('')` – which will sort purely numeric strings numerically, and prefixed strings alphabetically). Fixing that may be possible with a significantly more complex regex, but I gave up trying after about twenty minutes.

Comment: Thanks - interesting idea, nice use of the split and of the positive lookbehind - actually I already had an answer when I asked (posted) - I was half expecting to get a magic key that would mean "don't move". It would be interesting to see if actually variable list length vs the 2-tuples I use make any difference

Comment: Given that your 2-tuple approach uses a dummy `0` value in the case of no match, there should be no difference in the lexicographical ordering versus a variable-length sequence. It would be interesting to see a performance comparison between your solution and mine, though ...

Comment: Thank you for your generous bounty and drawing attention to my question - really appreciated :) I went with my code finally though, I like it short :D https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/commit/f66efa2a0c67f4e5b7b74cacd315755d13ded22c

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, your ultimate goal is to sort sub-sequences,
while leaving alone the items that are not part of the sub-sequences.

In your example, the sub-sequence is defined as *items starting with "B"*.
Your example list happens to contain items in lexicographic order,
which is a bit too convenient,
and can be distracting from finding a generalized solution.
Let's mix things up a little by using a different example list.
How about:

```
['X', 'B2', 'B11', 'B22', 'B', 'B1', 'B21', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

Here, the items are no longer ordered (at least I tried to organize them so that they are not), neither the ones starting with "B", nor the others.
However, the items starting with "B" still form a single contiguous sub-sequence, occupying the single range 1-6 rather than split ranges for example as 0-3 and 6-7.
This again might be distracting, I will address that aspect further down.

If I understand your ultimate goal correctly, you would like this list to get sorted like this:

```
['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

To make this work, we need a key function that will return a tuple, such that:

- First value:

  - If the item doesn't start with "B", then the index in the original list (or a value in the same order)
  - If the item starts with "B", then the index of the last item that didn't start with "B"
- Second value:

  - If the item doesn't start with "B", then omit this
  - If the item starts with "B", then the numeric value

This can be implemented like this, and with some [`doctests`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html):

```
def order_sublist(items):
    """
    >>> order_sublist(['A', 'B2', 'B11', 'B22', 'B', 'B1', 'B21', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2'])
    ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

    >>> order_sublist(['X', 'B2', 'B11', 'B22', 'B', 'B1', 'B21', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2'])
    ['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2']

    """
    def key():
        ord1 = [0]

        def inner(item):
            if not item.startswith('B'):
                ord1[0] += 1
                return ord1[0],
            return ord1[0], int(item[1:] or 0)
        return inner

    return sorted(items, key=key())
```

In this implementation, the items get sorted by these keys:

```
[(1,), (1, 2), (1, 11), (1, 22), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 21), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

The items not starting by "B" keep their order, thanks to the first value in the key tuple, and the items starting with "B" get sorted thanks to the second value of the key tuple.

This implementation contains a few tricks that are worth explaining:

- The `key` function returns a tuple of 1 or 2 elements, as explained earlier: the non-B items have one value, the B items have two.
- The first value of the tuple is not exactly the original index, but it's good enough. The value before the first B item is 1, all the B items use the same value, and the values after the B get an incremented value every time. Since `(1,) < (1, x) < (2,)` where `x` can be anything, these keys will get sorted as we wanted them.

And now on to the "real" tricks :-)

- What's up with the `ord1 = [0]` and `ord1[0] += 1` ? This is a technique to change a non-local value in a function. Had I used simply `ord1 = 0` and `ord1 += 1` would not work, because `ord1` is a primitive value defined outside of the function. Without the `global` keyword it's neither visible nor reassignable. A primitive `ord1` value inside the `inner` function would shadow the outer primitive value. But `ord1` being a list, it's visible inside `inner`, and its content can be modified. Note that cannot be reassigned. If you replaced with `ord1[0] += 1` as `ord1 = [ord1[0] + 1]` which would result in the same value, it would not work, as in that case `ord1` at the left side is a local variable, shadowing the `ord1` in the outer scope, and *not* modifying its value.
- What's up with the `key` and `inner` functions? I thought it would be neat if the key function we will pass to `sorted` will be reusable. This simpler version works too:

  ```
  def order_sublist(items):
      ord1 = [0]

      def inner(item):
          if not item.startswith('B'):
              ord1[0] += 1
              return ord1[0],
          return ord1[0], int(item[1:] or 0)

      return sorted(items, key=inner)
  ```

  The important difference is that if you wanted to use `inner` twice, both uses would share the same `ord1` list. Which can be acceptable, as longs as the integer value `ord1[0]` doesn't overflow during the use. In this case you won't use the function twice, and even if you did probably there wouldn't be a risk of integer overflow, but as a matter of principle, it's nice to make the function clean and reusable by wrapping it as I did in my initial proposal. What the `key` function does is simply initialize `ord1 = [0]` in its scope, define the `inner` function, and return the `inner` function. This way `ord1` is effectively private, thanks to the closure. Every time you call `key()`, it returns a function that has its private, fresh `ord1` value.
- Last but not least, notice the [`doctests`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html): the `""" ... """` comment is more than just documentation, it's executable tests. The `>>>` lines are code to execute in a Python shell, and the following lines are the expected output. If you have this program in a file called `script.py`, you can run the tests with `python -m doctest script.py`. When all tests pass, you get no output. When a test fails, you get a nice report. It's a great way to verify that your program works, through demonstrated examples. You can have multiple test cases, separated by blank lines, to cover interesting corner cases. In this example there are two test cases, with your original sorted input, and the modified unsorted input.

However, as [@zero-piraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) has made an interesting remark:

> I can see that your solution relies on `sorted()` scanning the list left-to-right (which is reasonable – I can't imagine TimSort is going to be replaced or radically changed any time soon – but not guaranteed by Python AFAIK, and there are sorting algorithms that don't work like that).

I tried to be self-critical and doubt that the scanning from left to right is reasonable.
But I think it is.
After all, the sorting really happens based on the keys,
not the actual values.
I think most likely Python does something like this:

1. Take a list of the key values with `[key(value) for value in input]`, visiting the values from left to right.
2. `zip` the list of keys with the original items
3. Apply whatever sorting algorithm on the zipped list, comparing items by the first value of the zip, and swapping items
4. At the end, return the sorted items with `return [t[1] for t in zipped]`

When building the list of key values,
it *could* work on multiple threads,
let's say two, the first thread one populating the first half and the second thread populating the second half in parallel.
That would mess up the `ord1[0] += 1` trick.
But I doubt it does this kind of optimization,
as it simply seems overkill.

But to eliminate any shadow of doubt,
we can follow this alternative implementation strategy ourselves,
though the solution becomes a bit more verbose:

```
def order_sublist(items):
    """
    >>> order_sublist(['A', 'B2', 'B11', 'B22', 'B', 'B1', 'B21', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2'])
    ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

    >>> order_sublist(['X', 'B2', 'B11', 'B22', 'B', 'B1', 'B21', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2'])
    ['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2']

    """
    ord1 = 0
    zipped = []
    for item in items:
        if not item.startswith('B'):
            ord1 += 1
        zipped.append((ord1, item))

    def key(item):
        if not item[1].startswith('B'):
            return item[0],
        return item[0], int(item[1][1:] or 0)

    return [v for _, v in sorted(zipped, key=key)]
```

Do note that thanks to the doctests,
we have an easy way to verify that the alternative implementation still works as before.

---

What if you wanted this example list:

```
['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B22', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2', 'B21']
```

To get sorted like this:

```
['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'C', 'Q1', 'C11', 'C2', 'B22']
```

That is, the items starting with "B" sorted by their numeric value,
*even when they don't form a contiguous sub-sequence*?

That won't be possible with a magical key function.
It certainly is possible though, with some more legwork.
You could:

1. Create a list with the original indexes of the items starting with "B"
2. Create a list with the items starting with "B" and sort it with whatever way you like
3. Write back the content of the sorted list at the original indexes

If you need help with this last implementation, let me know.

Comment: Interesting! Would you mind explaining the implementation in more detail? For example ... 1: I can see that your solution relies on `sorted()` scanning the list left-to-right (which is reasonable – I can't imagine TimSort is going to be replaced or radically changed any time soon – but not guaranteed by Python AFAIK, and there are sorting algorithms that don't work like that). 2: You don't explain the way `ord` simulates `nonlocal` with a list, which is going to be novel and perhaps confusing to some.

Comment: "Your example list happens to contain items in lexicographic order" -> yep, the use case actually was a list of strings that was sorted to begin with, but lexicographic order which from the user's standpoint didn't make much sense (`B1 B11 B2` vs `B1 B2 B11`) - hence the hunt for a key function (or algorithm) that would do minimal work - aka would leave things in place except if they met a specific criterion (like B + digits or .* plus digits). The more we think about it however, the more it seems that these tuple keys (which would however resort the whole list) are the only possible solution

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: simulating nonlocal with a list is the only way to do it in python2 unfortunately but yes it's a bit whoops - now that I read it actually it's an admittedly smart way of using the original indexes, interesting ! Re: the items starting with "B" sorted by their numeric value, even when they don't form a contiguous sub-sequence -> see [Sort a subset of a python list to have the same relative order as in other list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30504317/281545)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D yes, I understand why janos used the list, given the python-2.7 tag. I just think someone who's never seen the idiom before is liable to get confused without an explanation of what's actually going on, especially since the implementation is quite "clever" in other ways too. As I said, I just think a plain English explanation of what it's doing would help ... and I'd like to see this answer get some upvotes; it's neat :-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I added more explanation, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thorough! Thanks for this :-) BTW, I hadn't actually been thinking of threads, but e.g. a quicksort that calculates `key(x)` for a random pivot before doing anything else ... but the point is moot; we can at the very least rely on Python 2.7 not changing, and TimSort seems safe in 3.x for now too.

Comment: _What's up with the key and inner functions?_ `key` should be a class with a `__call__` method. Then you don't need to jump through hoops to get at your static variable and would have no concerns with using it multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers focused on the B's while I needed a more general solution as noted. Here's one:

```
def _order_by_number(items):
    regex = re.compile('(.*?)(\d*)$') # pass as an argument for generality
    keys = {k: regex.match(k) for k in items}
    keys = {k: (v.groups()[0], int(v.groups()[1] or 0)) 
            for k, v in keys.items()}
    items.sort(key=keys.__getitem__)
```

I am still looking for a magic key however that would leave stuff in place

Comment: As written, this doesn't actually sort at all, because your regex isn't doing what you think: for example, `[re.compile(u'(.+)(\d*)$').match(x).groups() for x in ['A', 'B1', 'C23']] == [('A', ''), ('B1', ''), ('C23', '')]`. Replacing the regex with `(.*?)(\d*)$` does do what you intend (and guarantees a match, allowing you to simplify the rest of your code).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it seems to me that a true "don't move" key would have to know about each item's initial position in the sequence, complicating matters significantly (for a start, I'd want to have a completely unambiguous definition of "don't move" for all possible cases, which I think is a tougher proposition than is immediately obvious).

Comment: In any case, +1 from me as soon as the regex problem is fixed :-) I'm tempted to slap a bounty on this question to see if it attracts more interest; the problem is an interesting one. Presumably you wouldn't object?

Comment: Not at all thanks - yep - I butchered up the regex in there, I can't ever seem to get those right on the first try.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus " it seems to me that a true "don't move" key would have to know about each item's initial position in the sequence, complicating matters significantly" -> yes, I initially thought of enumerating the initial (sorted) sequence and manipulating those numbers but it is indeed complicated

Comment: Ok, I'll add a bounty once the 48 hour time limit is up. I've edited the question slightly in advance to avoid a further slew of over-literal solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) module:

```
>>> from natsort import natsorted
>>> 
>>> a = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
>>> natsorted(a)
['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Answer (score 1):

### **If the elements that are to be sorted are all adjacent to each other in the list:**

You can use `cmp` in the `sorted()`-function instead of `key`:

```
s1=['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

def compare(a,b):
    if (a[0],b[0])==('B','B'): #change to whichever condition you'd like
        inta=int(a[1:] or 0)
        intb=int(b[1:] or 0)
        return cmp(inta,intb)  #change to whichever mode of comparison you'd like
    else:
        return 0               #if one of a, b doesn't fulfill the condition, do nothing

sorted(s1,cmp=compare)
```

This assumes transitivity for the comparator, which is not true for a more general case. This is also much slower than using `key`, but the advantage is that it can take context into account (to a small extent).

### **If the elements that are to be sorted are *not* all adjacent to each other in the list:**

You could generalise the comparison-type sorting algorithms by checking every other element in the list, and not just neighbours:

```
s1=['11', '2', 'A', 'B', 'B11', 'B21', 'B1', 'B2', 'C', 'C11', 'C2', 'B09','C8','B19']

def cond1(a):           #change this to whichever condition you'd like
    return a[0]=='B'

def comparison(a,b):    #change this to whichever type of comparison you'd like to make
    inta=int(a[1:] or 0)
    intb=int(b[1:] or 0)
    return cmp(inta,intb)

def n2CompareSort(alist,condition,comparison):
    for i in xrange(len(alist)):
        for j in xrange(i):
            if condition(alist[i]) and condition(alist[j]):
                if comparison(alist[i],alist[j])==-1:
                    alist[i], alist[j] = alist[j], alist[i]  #in-place swap

n2CompareSort(s1,cond1,comparison)
```

---

I don't think that any of this is less of a hassle than making a separate list/tuple, but it is "in-place" and leaves elements that don't fulfill our condition untouched.

Comment: +1, but note for Python 3 you'll need to write `cmp` yourself and use `functools.cmp_to_key`. Also I feel like it should be possible to apply a cmp-sort directly even if the elements are not adjacent

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following key function. It will return a tuple of the form `(letter, number)` if there is a number, or of the form `(letter,)` if there is no number. This works since `('A',) < ('A', 1)`.

```
import re

a = ['A', 'B' ,'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def order(e):
    num = regex.findall(e)
    if num:
        num = int(num[0])
        return e[0], num
    return e,

print(sorted(a, key=order))
>> ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Comment: That's the idea (as noted in Zero's answer I had similar, see my answer) - would this work for strings with groups of numbers at random locations ? - only the last group should matter

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question clear, you are trying to **sort an array by two attributes**; the **alphabet** and the trailing **'number'**.

You could just do something like

```
data = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
data.sort(key=lambda elem: (elem[0], int(elem[1:]))
```

but since this would throw an exception for elements without a number trailing them, we can go ahead and just make a function (we *shouldn't be using lambda* anyways!)

```
def sortKey(elem):
     try:
             attribute = (elem[0], int(elem[1:]))
     except:
             attribute = (elem[0], 0)

     return attribute
```

With this sorting key function made, we can sort the element in place by

```
data.sort(key=sortKey)
```

Also, you could just go ahead and adjust the sortKey function to give priority to certain alphabets if you wanted to.

Comment: That's for one item strings before the number

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D yes. But using a regex and getting an index of the trailing number within try-exept would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To answer precisely what you describe you can do this :

```
l = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2', 'D']


def custom_sort(data, c):
    s = next(i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x.startswith(c))
    e = next((i for i, x in enumerate(data) if not x.startswith(c) and i > s), -1)
    return data[:s] + sorted(data[s:e], key=lambda d: int(d[1:] or -1)) + data[e:]


print(custom_sort(l, "B"))
```

if you what an complete sort you can simply do this (as @Mike JS Choi answered but simplier) :

```
output = sorted(l, key=lambda elem: (elem[0], int(elem[1:] or -1)))
```

Comment: That's for one item strings before the number - I am interested in a more general solution - the B's are just an example. Plus list concatenation is not always a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use ord() to transform for exemple 'B11' in numerical value:

```
cells = ['B11', 'C1', 'A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C11', 'C2', 'B']
conv_cells = []

## Transform expression in numerical value.
for x, cell in enumerate(cells):
    val = ord(cell[0]) * (ord(cell[0]) - 65) ## Add weight to ensure respect order.
    if len(cell) > 1:
        val += int(cell[1:])
    conv_cells.append((val, x)) ## List of tuple (num_val, index).

## Display result.
for x in sorted(conv_cells):
    print(str(cells[x[1]]) + ' - ' + str(x[0]))
```

Comment: B and C are just example strings - these are no ordinals necessarilly

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to sort with different rules for different subgroups you may use tuples as sorting keys. In this case items would be grouped and sorted layer by layer: first by first tuple item, next in each subgroup by second tuple item and so on. This allows us to have different sorting rules in different subgroups. The only limit -  items should be comparable within each group. For example, you cannot have `int` and `str` type keys in the same subgroup, but you can have them in different subgroups.

Lets try to apply it to the task. We will prepare tuples with elements types (`str`, `int`) for B elements, and tuples with (`str`, `str`) for all others.

```
def sorter(elem):
    letter, num = elem[0], elem[1:]
    if letter == 'B':
        return letter, int(num or 0)  # hack - if we've got `''` as num, replace it with `0`
    else:
        return letter, num

data = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

sorted(data, key=sorter)
# returns
['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

**UPDATE**

If you prefer it in one line:

```
data = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

sorted(data, key=lambda elem: (elem[0],  int(elem[1:] or 0) if elem[0]=='B' else elem[:1]
# result
['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Anyway these key functions are quite simple, so you can adopt them to real needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def sort_with_prefix(list, prefix):
    alist = np.array(list)
    ix = np.where([l.startswith(prefix) for l in list])

    alist[ix] =  [prefix + str(n or '')
             for n in np.sort([int(l.split(prefix)[-1] or 0) 
                              for l in alist[ix]])]
    return alist.tolist()
```

For example:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']

print(sort_with_prefix(l, 'B'))
>> ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just *key* and the precondition that the sequence is already 'sorted':

```
import re

s = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']

def subgroup_ordinate(element):
    # Split the sequence element values into groups and ordinal values.
    # use a simple regex and int() in this case
    m = re.search('(B)(.+)', element)  
    if m:
        subgroup = m.group(1)
        ordinate = int(m.group(2))
    else:
        subgroup = element
        ordinate = None
    return (subgroup, ordinate)

print sorted(s, key=subgroup_ordinate)

['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

The `subgroup_ordinate()` function does two things: identifies groups to be sorted and also determines the ordinal number within the groups. This example uses regular expression but the function could be arbitrarily complex. For example we can change it to `ur'(B|C)(.+)'` and sort both B and C sequences .

```
['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Reading the bounty question carefully I note the requirement 'sorts some values while leaving others "in place"'. Defining the comparison function to return 0 for elements that are not in subgroups would leave these elements where they were in the sequence.

```
s2 = ['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'A', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']

def compare((_a,a),(_b,b)):
    return 0 if a is None or b is None else cmp(a,b)

print sorted(s, compare, subgroup_ordinate)

['X', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'A', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compound_sort(input_list, natural_sort_prefixes=()):
    padding = '{:0>%s}' % len(max(input_list, key=len))
    return sorted(
        input_list, 
        key = lambda li: \
            ''.join(
                [li for c in '_' if not li.startswith(natural_sort_prefixes)] or 
                [c for c in li if not c.isdigit()] + \
                [c for c in padding.format(li) if c.isdigit()]
            )
        )
```

This sort method receives:

- `input_list`: The `list` to be sorted,
- `natural_sort_prefixes`: A `string` or a `tuple` of `string`s.

List items targeted by the `natural_sort_prefixes` will be sorted *naturally*. Items not matching those prefixes will be sorted *lexicographically*.

This method assumes that the list items are structured as one or more non-numerical characters followed by one or more digits.

It should be more performant than solutions using regex, and doesn't depend on external libraries.

You can use it like:

```
print compound_sort(['A', 'B' , 'B11', 'B1', 'B2', 'C11', 'C2'], natural_sort_prefixes=("A","B"))

# ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'C11', 'C2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

a = ['A', 'B' , 'B1', 'B11', 'B2', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C11', 'C2']
dict = OrderedDict()

def get_str(item):
  _str = list(map(str, re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]", item)))
  return _str

def get_digit(item):
  _digit = list(map(int, re.findall(r"\d+", item)))
  return _digit

for item in a:
  _str = get_str(item)
  dict[_str[0]] = sorted([get_digit(dig) for dig in a if _str[0] in dig])

nested_result = [[("{0}{1}".format(k,v[0]) if v else k) for v in dict[k]] for k in dict.keys()]
print (nested_result)
# >>> [['A'], ['B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22'], ['C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']]

result = []
for k in dict.keys():
  for v in dict[k]:
    result.append("{0}{1}".format(k,v[0]) if v else k)
print (result)
# >>> ['A', 'B', 'B1', 'B2', 'B11', 'B21', 'B22', 'C', 'C1', 'C2', 'C11']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort an arbitrary subset of elements while leaving other elements in place, it can be useful to design a *view* over the original list.
The idea of a view in general is that it's like a lens over the original list, but modifying it will manipulate the underlying original list.
Consider this helper class:

```
class SubList:
    def __init__(self, items, predicate):
        self.items = items
        self.indexes = [i for i in range(len(items)) if predicate(items[i])]

    @property
    def values(self):
        return [self.items[i] for i in self.indexes]

    def sort(self, key):
        for i, v in zip(self.indexes, sorted(self.values, key=key)):
            self.items[i] = v
```

The constructor saves the original list in `self.items`, and the original indexes in `self.indexes`, as determined by `predicate`. In your examples, the `predicate` function can be this:

```
def predicate(item):
    return item.startswith('B')
```

Then, the `values` property is the lens over the original list,
returning a list of values picked from the original list by the original indexes.

Finally, the `sort` function uses `self.values` to sort,
and then modifies the original list.

Consider this demo with doctests:

```
def demo(values):
    """
    >>> demo(['X', 'b3', 'a', 'b1', 'b2'])
    ['X', 'b1', 'a', 'b2', 'b3']

    """
    def predicate(item):
        return item.startswith('b')
    sub = SubList(values, predicate)

    def key(item):
        return int(item[1:])
    sub.sort(key)

    return values
```

Notice how `SubList` is used only as a tool through which to manipulate the input `values`. After the `sub.sort` call, `values` is modified, with elements to sort selected by the `predicate` function, and sorted according to the `key` function, and all other elements never moved.

Using this `SubList` helper with appropriate `predicate` and `key` functions,
you can sort arbitrary selection of elements of a list.