# How to sort a list, only sorting strings?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of strings and integers and want to sort the list, preserving the numbers like so

```
["Hello", 1, 2, "World", 6, "Foo", 3]
```

would become

```
["Foo", 1, 2, "Hello", 6, "World", 3]
```

In short, it only sorts the strings in the list, not the integers, which stay in place. I've tried using the `key` parameter with `list.sort()` but haven't managed to achieve what I want.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: this is different to the linked question as I want to preserve the integers' indexes, rather than sort them along with the strings.

EDIT: this is different to the second linked question as answers from that question can solve the problem using the `key` parameter, something I have explicitly stated does not work in this instance.

Comment: Not sure why my comment was deleted, this is certainly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737145/sort-a-sublist-of-elements-in-a-list-leaving-the-rest-in-place

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Picked up this cool trick from @JonClements the other day.

Here goes:

```
gen = iter(sorted([x for x in lst if isinstance(x, str)]))
new_lst =  [next(gen) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst]
print(new_lst)
# ['Foo', 1, 2, 'Hello', 6, 'World', 3]
```

Sort the strings separately and create a generator expression from the sorted strings. In a *list comprehension*, pick objects alternately from the gen. exp. using a ternary conditional if only the items in the original position is a string, otherwise, pick an item (an integer) from the initial list.

Comment: I actually upvoted this solution. But I know of down voters who cast votes based solely on the fact that your solution is O(n^2) and doubles the memory footprint of the original array.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I seen an analog Q&A, with odd & even numbers. Is that the same one?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, that one.

Comment: @MatthewCole Why is this not O(nlog n)?

Comment: The only way this could get more beautiful is if there existed a lazy sorting algorithm.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye could be slightly faster by forcing the list comprehension in `sort`: `gen = iter(sorted([x for x in l if isinstance(x,str)]))` since it needs to build it anyway. (BTW we spend way too much time on this site)

Comment: @MatthewCole how do you figure this is O(n^2)?

Comment: @JaredGoguen on second thought I think you're right. When I first saw the iterator wrapped around the sort function call, I thought O(n^2). But `sorted()` shouldn't need to be called each time the `next()` function is called.

Comment: @MatthewCole right. `gen` is an iterator over a sorted list.

Comment: If you were really worried about auxiliary space, you could modify the original list in-place using `l[:] = (next(gen) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst)`, which would then only require a list of `len` M where M is the number of integers in your original list.

Comment: @MatthewCole wrong: `sorted` returns a `list`. Sorting is done only once. iteration only comes on the completed list, just to provide an element at a time and be able to use the ternary & the listcomp (that's the JonClements nice touch Moses was talking about)

Answer (score 8):

First, sorting of an heterogenous list like this only works in Python 2. But the result is not what you need.

I would create a iterator on the sorted version of the filtered list (keeping only string) and rebuild the list with either an item of this iterator or the original list depending on the element type:

```
l = ["Hello", 1, 2, "World", 6, "Foo", 3]

sgen = iter(sorted([x for x in l if isinstance(x,str)]))

result = [next(sgen) if isinstance(x,str) else x for x in l]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['Foo', 1, 2, 'Hello', 6, 'World', 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you sort the array only with string in extracting it, then you replace the strings step by step in the original array :

```
l = ["Foo", 1, 2, "Hello", 6, "World", 3]

s = [x for x in l if type(x) == str]
s.sort()

j = 0
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if type(x) == str:
       l[i] = s[j]
       j += 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.